# Multiple svn repositories privileges

Tags: svn, apache, authentication, version-control, virtualhost

I have configured two repositories sites on my server. The first is on `/home/svn/repoA` and the second on `/home/svn/repoB`.

I have built a virtualhost on Apache with this information:

```
<Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /home/svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Servidor SVN"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Now this the URL, I can get access to the server with `http://svn.mydomain.com/repoA` and `http://svn.mydomain.com/repoB`, but I want to make the repoB private, only allow access with a user and password previously created with the htpasswd on dav_svn.passwd.

If I take out the `<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>` line, and it's closer tag, it asks me the user and the password, but in the two repositories.

Is there a way to make one readable only for anonymous and read/write for logged users and the second repository only read/write rights for logged users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What resources have you used to get this far?  I know there is a free Subversion book (Version Control with Subversion) that has the answer in it:

Apache authn/authz: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz

Path-based authz: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I've choosed the Path-based, i have configured the files like the message above but it take's me the following message: Invalid command 'AuthSVNAccessFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration. I've looked the file that loads the modules and it points to the right folder, and the files are in it. Do you get a response to that error? thanks

Comment: Have you loaded the mod_authz_svn module into Apache?

Comment: i've had writen this on the httpd.conf

LoadModule dav_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so

but gets the same error

Comment: It should be AuthzSVNAccessFile, not AuthSVNAccessFile.  Sorry I didn't see this earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just have 2 location blocks. RepoA should have "Satisfy Any" turned on in the Apache location block for anonymous read-only access, and a corresponding Auth file allowing anonymous access. RepoB's Auth file should deny anonymous access.

i.e.

Apache repoA conf

```
<Location /repoA>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /home/svn/repoA
  AuthType Basic

  Satisfy Any
  AuthName "Servidor SVN"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/authFileA
</Location>
```

authFileA

```
[/]
* = r

[/repoA]
* = r
mark = rw
bill = rw
```

Apache repoB conf

```
<Location /repoB>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /home/svn/repoB
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Servidor SVN"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/authFileB
</Location>
```

authFileB

```
[/]
* =

[/repoB]
* = 
mark = rw
bill = rw
```

Comment: ok, i have done it but now it says this:
Invalid command 'AuthSVNAccessFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: I don't know  if you need something about server info, it is a Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS with the apache php5, mysql and svn standard installation

Comment: Invalid command 'AuthSVNAccessFile' can probably be solved by installing the module using: "a2enmod authz_svn"